# How to move JSON from MySQL to Elasticsearch with Debezium?

Tags: mysql, elasticsearch, apache-kafka, debezium

I'm trying to move a field from MySQL with type : JSON to Elasticsearch.
 Currently, I'm getting this error: `object mapping for myobject tried to parse field myobject as object, but found a concrete value` 
Elasticsearch connector :

```
 "config": {
    "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSinkConnector",
    "type.name": "lab",
    "behavior.on.null.values": "delete",
    "tasks.max": "1",
    "topics": "customer_db.retentions.notifs",
    "transforms": "unwrap,key",
    "key.ignore": "false",
    "transforms.key.field": "ID",
    "transforms.key.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ExtractField$Key",
    "transforms.unwrap.drop.tombstones": "false",
    "name": "customer_notif",
    "transforms.unwrap.type": "io.debezium.transforms.ExtractNewRecordState",
    "connection.url": "http://X.X.X.X:9200"
  }
```

In MySQL, the object looks like this :

```
 {ID: "2957658787337710", BetaID: "29576587921124", Reference: "411"}
```

But after CDC with Debezium, the message in Kafka looks like this :

```
[{\"ID\":\"2957658787337710\",\"BetaID\":\"29576587921124\",\"Reference\":\"411\"}]
```

Comment: You should show what the actual record looks like.

Comment: I've updated it. Please have a look.

Comment: AFAIK, Debezium is going to read that whole column as a string. You can refer Debezium source code to confirm. You'd have to write your own transform plugin to parse the data

Comment: Could you add some references for the same?

Comment: The documentation explicitly says JSON columns become strings, so it's unclear why you expect something different https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/connectors/mysql.html#mysql-data-types

Comment: Yes, but could I use the semantic type for processing the string?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the term "semantic type", but Debezium doesn't process the string itself. You'd have to use Kafka Streams/KSQL to parse the data into a structured format prior to writing to Elasticsearch documents